# MVC 4 Web Api Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

I've spent days trying to find examples, but none appear to answer what it is I am looking for. Most other examples are for later versions of Web API.

I am currently consuming a REST web service, that uses basic authentication. I want to emulate this in mine. The path is /api/authenticate

I pass a header of Authorization Basic [base 64 username / password]. The response I am currently seeing is a response code of 200, and a json response that has the session token (among other things).

For future calls, I then pass the session token in an X header back to the server, and that then passes all of my calls.

I'm trying to write a web api that works in a very similar way.

I've done very little with web api, so am a bit lost. Here is what I have so far...

```
    public string[] Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        if (Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }
        else
        {
            // Check for valid users
            string authToken = Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
            string decodedToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authToken));
            string username = decodedToken.Substring(0, decodedToken.IndexOf(":"));
            string password = decodedToken.Substring(decodedToken.IndexOf(":") + 1);

            if (username == "MyApiUserName" && password == "MyApiPassword")
            {
                // The line below doesn't work yet.
                //WebSecurity.Login(model.Username, model.Password, persistCookie: true);
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Test", "Something");
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

                Pair[0] = username;
                Pair[1] = password;

                return Pair;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

What I need is to respond once authenticated with a session token in the json response and I also need to know how to use that session token in my other API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net Api has its own authentication methods, so you don't need to implement them by yourself. this is why all examples are for latest versions of Web API.

if you want return json responce try to use JsonResult instead of string[ ]

see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: As it's a web api, it will return JSON anyway... in the return after the authentication, the string[] is being returned as a json array. I was having problems trying to return a JsonResult... as Json in return Json("something") was putting a red line under "Json".

Comment: I guss it   put a red line under "Json" because you define the method to return array of string not json

modify it to retutn ActionResult  as in the example here 

public ActionResult Movies()
{

    return Json(movies, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

Comment: Inside an ApiController? I have just done as you have suggested and still getting red underline on Json.